# How to configure CORS on a Express Route using "cors" library

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I need to enable CORS on every endpoint for POST requests that matches `/api/v1/support/*` path.

I'm making a POST request to `/api/v1/support/graphql` with credentials true, but the preflight request (the OPTIONS one) returns a 401. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my configuration (note that I have changed the actual domain for a dummy in this sample below):

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: /mydomain\.com$/,
  credentials: true,
  maxAge: 3600
};
app.options('/api/v1/support/*', cors(corsOptions));
app.post('/api/v1/support/*', cors(corsOptions));

// graphQLRouter is an instance of express.Router()
app.use('/api/v1/support/graphql', [ fowardIP, validateTokenInCookie ], graphQLRouter);
```

Comment: on the server is request.OPTIONS legal per the spec  ie   Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '.....,OPTIONS'  so in addition to the browser making the 'preflight' request, you also may have to adjust server to conform to the spec .. see 'ALLOW_ORIGIN' , 'ALLOW_METHODS' , 'ALLOW_HEADERS' under access_control headers

Comment: Browsers don't send credentials in CORS preflight OPTIONS requests. And apparently somewhere in your application code, you have authentication required for the `/api/v1/support/graphql` route, which is fine for the POST request, because if you have your frontend code sending the credentials as part of that POST, that'll work as expected. But it's not fine for the OPTIONS request. That needs to work without any credentials being sent ー without the server requiring authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this. Setting access control also

```js
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin(origin, callback) {
    callback(null, true);
  },
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,token');
  next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

This may help you

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. What's wrong with my configuration?